# Triangulation of 3D points with K vertices per face

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, shapes, triangulation

I'm working with Three.js. I have a collection of **3D points** (x, y, z) and a collection of faces. One face is composed of **K points**. It can be as well convex as concave.
I found nothing that could help me in the Three.js documentation. One solution could be to triangulate those shapes, but so far I haven't found any simple 3D triangulation algorithm.

The other solution would be doing something like that :

```
var pointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 0));
pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0));
pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 3, 0));
pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 3, 0));
pointsGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

var mesh = new THREE.Shape/ShapeGeometry/Something(pointsGeometry, material);
group.add(mesh);

scene.add(group);
```

I have a lot of these shapes that build together a closed surface.

Any suggestion?

Thank you for your attention.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed out, there are 2 ways to achieve that :

- use a 3D triangulation algorithm (not provided by Three.js) ;
- use the 2D triangulation algorithm normally used for Three.js `Shape` objects with some transformation applied upon each face of the geometry.

The last one seems cool but unfortunately, as I tried out I realized it's not that trivial. I came up with something similar to what Paul-Jan said :

For each face of your geometry :

1. Compute the centroid the face ;
2. Compute the face normal ;
3. Compute the matrix of the face ;
4. Project the 3D points onto the 2D plane of the face ;
5. Create the geometry (triangulated with the `Shape` triangulation algorithm) ;
6. Apply the face matrix to the newly created geometry
7. Create a `Mesh` and add it to an `Object3D` (I tried to merged all the geometries into 1, but it fails with the `ShapeBufferGeometry`)

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q0auhuq/8/).

Be careful to the [winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) of your vertices or put the `THREE.Material.side` to `THREE.DoubleSide` to prevent faces from being culled.

Comment: I already know that the points are coplanar, so I can easily calculate the normal of the plane, project the plane and the points to the X,Y plane. I already have an own 2D triangulation algorithm. afterward I don't need to reverse the points to the previous plane, because i just need their order, Afterwards , with order of the points I can easily form the triangles and send them to three.js an build an object with the buffer geometry (It looks like i cannot tag you ) but thanks and the demo is great, I'm to test it with my data and see if it fits with my system :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to revisit the Three.js documentation, and the [Shape](https://threejs.org/docs/api/extras/core/Shape.html) object in particular. The sample code on that page uses `bezierCurveTo`, but if you use [lineTo](https://threejs.org/docs/api/extras/core/Path.html) in stead you can feed it your sequences of points and create concave polygons (including holes).

Comment: The OP has to deal with 3D Points, but the [triangulation algorithm of Three.js Shape](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/ShapeUtils.js) works with 2D points. A transformation is needed for each face of the polygon before passing to `Shape`.

Comment: Ah, good point. I was under the expression that you could just feed it 3D points and things would work out automatically, thanks for the correction! Now you would have to first project the points of each face on their own plane and transform the shape back to the correct orientation afterwards. Not very practical for a non-trivial amount of faces.

Comment: @Paul-Jan thanks fot the answer , yeah, sadly it doesn't works with 3d point. Afterwards i came up with the same conclusion.