# distorted Mesh with threejs

Tags: graphics, three.js, mesh

Hi I am trying to draw a model in threejs.
I tried drawing it with lines resulting in [a correct representation of the bim model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zPZI.png).
Drawing it with a mesh results in [a distorted model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDC0.png)

My approach to drawing it with a Mesh is

```
let vertices = [];
for (let part of this.BUILDINGINFORMATION) {
  for (let point of part.Polyhedron.Points) {
    vertices.push(point);
  }
}
let holes = [];
let triangles, mesh;
this.GEOMETRY= new THREE.Geometry();
this.GEOMETRY.vertices = vertices;
triangles = new THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape(vertices, holes);
for (let i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
  this.GEOMETRY.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2]));
}
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.GEOMETRY, material);
```

Answer (score 0):

as a disclaimer, I don't have any experience with threeJS or JS in general.

First of all, you should not combine all vertices from all parts into one vertex array. 
Make separate arrays for each part, or maybe even each polyhedron.

With that being said, from the documentation, it seems that ShapeUtils.triangulateShape only works on 2D collections of points. And if I'm interpreting your first picture correctly, your points are actually 3D.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/ShapeUtils.triangulateShape

[Triangulation of 3D points with K vertices per face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393306/triangulation-of-3d-points-with-k-vertices-per-face)
This thread might give you some ideas on how you could reduce each face to 2D.

However, did you try pushing the points you have directly as faces, creating a mesh for each part?

Comment: Thank you for your answer !  The way I get the data is that there is a wall for example, and I get all its vertices. The problem is that I have no information what shape that element has so that I cannot safely assign vertices to a face without assuming its shape. A workaround I found was to create a convex hull and get the faces via that, but I am at a loss how to do that